# indexPath nil after changing to UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard

Since I changed my view to a UITableViewController in Storyboard, my indexPath is nil. Can someone spot the error? I use segues. I have connected the dummy cell from the TableViewController to the new TableViewController. Both are pushed within a UINavigationController

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"selectCountry" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Assume self.view is the table view
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    Country *country = (Country *)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:path];

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"selectCountry"])
    {
        CaveTableViewController *ctvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        ctvc.country = country;
        ctvc.navigationItem.title = country.country;
    }

    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:path animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing :

```
NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

To :

```
NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
```

Comment: Hi. sender is of Type "CountryTableViewController *" which is the class. How do I get the cell?

Comment: Assuming you have a custom cell class named CountryCell you get the cell with :
CountryCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: I don't have a custom cell. And indexPath is nil.

Comment: What do you have in the console if you put an NSLog(@"Index Path : %@ :: Section : %d :: Row : %d",indexPath, indexPath.section, indexPath.row)
Your code seems ok, indexPath should not be nil, is your cell selectable in the nib file ?

Comment: The problem is solved... I cleaned the project, did all the linking again and it worked... :/